# Change report from one-side to two-sided

Tags: double-sided, printing, report, layout

I wrote my diploma thesis in a one-sided layout (report) and now I want to print it, but don't want to have the back page blank on every single page. So I want to change the paper format to a two-sided layout in order to have a different offset on odd and even pages.
For that reason, I changed my preamble which looks like this now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.8em}{3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@lstlisting{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.8em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=12pt
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}

    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter\ #1}}
    \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\sl\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\sl\rightmark}}
    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\sl\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\sffamily\sl\thepage}}
    \cfoot{}

\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the following PDF is generated:

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

Obviously, the offset is the wrong way around. Page 1 should have the offset of page 2 and inverse.
Does somebody know a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are having this inconsistent margin is because you are manually adjusting the `textwidth` when you write `\addtolength{\textwidth}{...}`. A better way to achieve this is to set the width of the inner and outer margins using the `geometry` package (which should be loaded last I think). An exaggerated solution (where I also adjust the top height rather than doing `\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}`) would use:

```latex
\usepackage[showframe, left=50mm, right=20mm, top=20mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @Oliver perhaps consider up voting...

Comment: I did it, but sadly it doesn't count. When I upvote, I get following message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.